# Oracle datatype error

Tags: sql, oracle, etl

I'm trying to insert a value into `date` datatype by selecting a value from a source table whose column is also `date` datatype. I have selected the column directly without doing any conversion using `to_date` function, because both are same types but I'm getting the following error:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected DATE got NUMBER
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
```

I had doubled checked, source column has no null values.

```
insert into Target(Targetdate) 
  select to_date(Source.START_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd')
    from Source
```

Thanks for looking into this.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you try to get the dates truncated to the day into the Target table. This can be done by doing so:

```
insert into Target(Targetdate) select trunc(Source.START_DATE,'DD') from Source
```

**EDIT**

Dazzal mentioned that as this is the default operation when leaving out the second parameter to TRUNC, so this is even a bit simpler:

```
insert into Target(Targetdate) select trunc(Source.START_DATE) from Source
```

The problem with your query was that `Source.START_DATE` is a date, not a string...

**EDIT2**

As it seems that you want to get date strings in a specific format - which has *nothing* to do with the date type, and how thigs are stored internally - just do this:

```
SELECT to_char(START_DATE,'YYYY-MM-DD' from Source;
```

- [Oracle TRUNC](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php)

Comment: as dd is default for a date input, you can omit the 2nd parameter to trunc.

Comment: @Dazzal Thanks, though I always leave it in - because I tend to forget the default behaviours of the functions :)

Comment: trunc did not solve my problem. To be more specific, a sample value of my source table is 11-JUN-13 and i need target value as YYYY-MM-DD how can i achieve this?

Comment: So you want a textual represenataion (e.g. a String) that reads `2011-06-13`? In that case, you should go with the answer @APC posted, and only format zour values when you select them... Also, I'd recommend you to step back a bit from coding, and get familiar with how a database system works basically, and how the data types are to be used...

Answer (score 1):

You said you are selecting a date column from source table. When it's date column, then why are you converting again into date? Of course it will give error also..

```
insert into Target(Targetdate) 
select to_date(Source.START_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd'), from Source
```

Input parameter of 'to_date' function is 'string'

```
to_date( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )
```

UPDATE1:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy-mm-dd';


insert into Target(Targetdate) 
select to_char(Source.START_DATE,'yyyy-mm-dd') from Source
```

Comment: actually, when I'm directly inserting the value I got this error. That is why I did this conversion

Comment: So both tables have same date format? Can you tell me the format of date in source table?

Comment: ok let me be more specific... example of my source value is 11-JUN-13 and i need target value as YYYY-MM-DD how can i achieve this?

Comment: @user1751356 "ok let me be more specific... example of my source value is 11-JUN-13 and i need target value as YYYY-MM-DD how can i achieve this" if both columns are `date` format then you dont have to worry about the format when storing the date. internally, a date is stored as a number. if you want a specific format when selecting then use `TO_CHAR(your_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or at the session level as `alter session set nls_date_format='yyyy-mm-dd';` but again this is only for displaying the result, not storing it!

Comment: Thank you. That made sense to me. But, why I'm getting this error when I'm trying to insert a value to the target.

Comment: try now..             and let me know

Comment: It is giving me missing comma error, and I have other columns also. I had double checked and there is no missing comma.

Comment: I think, there is a problem with this statement to_date(Targetdate,'yyyy-mm-dd')

Answer (score 1):

> "example of my source value is 11-JUN-13 and i need target value as
>   YYYY-MM-DD how can i achieve this? "

All Oracle dates are stored in the same internal format:

```
SQL>  select dump(sysdate) from dual;

DUMP(SYSDATE)
---------------------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: 221,7,1,3,10,22,8,0

SQL>
```

The display date is entirely dependent on the client environment's default values, or the format mask if we're using TO_CHAR().

If both your columns are the DATE datatype you have overcomplicated things: you do not need to cast the values in the INSERT.

```
insert into Target (Targetdate) 
select Source.START_DATE
from Source
```

You just need to apply a format mask when selecting the target date from `Target`.