# Change the date and time stamp format for data in the table

Tags: sql, oracle, date, timestamp-with-timezone

We have a huge Oracle database that contains data which has date and time stamps.
Right now we are using `mm-dd-yyyy format for date and EST Time zone for time stamp`.

Now we need to change the `date format as yyyy-mm-dd and time stamps should be GMT timezone`.
We need to change already existing data in the tables to this new format as well as newly inserted data.

Any help on how to achieve this?

Comment: My question is more similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11106703/change-timezone-component-of-timestamp-with-timezone-in-oracle. In addition i need date format change too.

Comment: As I explained in this answer to another recent question, the date format is a *display property* and has nothing to do with how the date is stored: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14144928/146325

Comment: @APC Yes for `date`. But `timestamp with time zone` the time zone information is actually stored in the database. See my answer.

Comment: @kmkaplan - I was merely pointing out the OP's misconception regarding date format. Obviously the timezone is data not presentation, and so the conversion needs to be addressed. I don't believe my comment says otherwise.

Comment: @APC Indeed. And I even plussed your comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the date format is *just a matter of presentation*. When selecting from you database, apply a format:

```
select to_char(sysdate, 'YYYY-MM-DD') from dual;
```

To get this format by default, set it in your session’s `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` parameter:

```
alter session set NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD';
```

You can also set the `NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` and `NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT`. See [Setting Up a Globalization Support Environment](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch3globenv.htm#g1012703) in Oracle’s documentation.

Regarding time zones, normally it is the application that inserts the `timestamp with time zone` in the database that chooses what time zone it puts. But the application that queries these timestamps can request to get them back in another time zone. Compare the following queries:

```
select systimestamp from dual; -- This gives you the timestamp in the server configured time zone
select systimestamp at time zone 'EST' from dual; -- This is in your EST time zone
select systimestamp at time zone '+00:00' from dual; -- Finally the same timestamp in UTC.
```

To force a certain time zone you can force it with an `after insert or update` trigger. Something like:

```
create or replace trigger my_table_force_utc_timestamps
before insert or update on my_table
for each row
begin
    :new.my_timestamp_with_tz := :new.my_timestamp_with_tz at time zone '+00:00';
end;
/
```

If you *really* want to convert your timestamps to UTC you can try:

```
update my_table set my_timestamp_with_tz = my_timestamp_with_tz at time zone '+00:00';
```

*Edit*: to change `sysdate` time zone before inserting into tables you must in fact use `systimestamp at time zone …` that will be cast to a date value:

```
insert into my_table (date_column) values (systimestamp at time zone '+00:00');
```

You can read more about time zones in Oracle’s documentation [Datetime and Time Zone Parameters and Environment Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/ch4datetime.htm#i1006532). With the example `table_dt` this would give:

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS';

Session modifiee.

SQL> CREATE TABLE table_dt (c_id NUMBER, c_dt DATE);

Table creee.

SQL> insert into table_dt values (1, systimestamp);

1 ligne creee.

SQL> insert into table_dt values (2, systimestamp at time zone '+00:00');

1 ligne creee.

SQL> select * from table_dt;

      C_ID C_DT
---------- ----------------------
         1 13-JANV.-2013 16:31:41
         2 13-JANV.-2013 15:32:08
```

Comment: This answer would be better if it majored on changing the timezones, which is the important matter.   THe date format is a red herring.

Comment: @APC You mean like reordering the two parts? Or using some formatting tricks to make it ovious that the second part is the big one?

Comment: @kmkaplan-today i checked my columns are of DATE type only with time in EST timezone. From my java side i am inserting sysdate into these columns. How can i change sysdate time zone before inserting into tables?

Comment: @kmkaplan-can u explain it with table_dt table as in the oracle link. I tried this insert query insert into table_dt values (9,sysdate at time zone '+00:00') as well as insert into table_dt(c_dt) values(sysdate at time zone '+00:00'). But getting this error ORA30084- invalid data type for datetime primary with time zone modifier.

Comment: @Abhishekkumar That’s my fault. Dates do *not* have a time zone. To be able to operate on time zones in Oracle you need a `timestamp`. So you need to insert `systimestamp at time zone '+00:00'`. I edited the answer to fix this and to show an example with the `table_dt` from Oracle’s documentation.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [new_time](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/new_time.php) oracle function

```
SELECT to_char(new_time(to_date('01-03-2013','mm-dd-yyyy HH24:MI'), 
                        'EST', 'GMT'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI') d
FROM DUAL;
```

Use this to test on your database:

```
SELECT to_char(new_time(sysdate, 'EST', 'GMT'),'yyyy-mm-dd HH24:MI') d
FROM DUAL;
```